# SMOS time series and export to CSV in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, csv, time-series

I'm new to Google Earth Engine.

I'm trying to create a time-series of SMOS for a point. I have selected the coordinates of the point and am now trying to export the table as a .csv.

My script so far is:

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("NASA_USDA/HSL/soil_moisture").select('ssm');

// Define a region of interest as a buffer around a point.
var geom = ee.Geometry.Point(40.44, 3.12).buffer(500);

// Create and print the chart.
print(ui.Chart.image.series(collection, geom, ee.Reducer.mean(), 30));

// Export the time-series as a csv.
Export.table.toDrive({collection: ssm, description: 'mandera', 
  selectors: 'date, value', fileFormat: 'CSV'});
```

I know I'm very close to what I need but I can't seem to be able to figure out how to export the timeseries as a .csv file in my Drive. Also, how can I name the file so I find it once it's exported?

I have seen the answer to this: 
[Create time series and export it to csv GEE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299108/create-time-series-and-export-it-to-csv-gee)
But I think I might be missing a step...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To export a CSV, you first want to create an `ee.FeatureCollection`. You can map over your collection, and call `reduceRegion()` with an `ee.Reducer.mean()` reducer to get the mean value for each image. Use that value to construct a feature to return. The resulting feature collection is what you should export.

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("NASA_USDA/HSL/soil_moisture").select('ssm');

// Define a region of interest as a buffer around a point.
var geom = ee.Geometry.Point(40.44, 3.12).buffer(500);

var timeSeries = collection.map(function (image) {
  var date = image.date().format('yyyy-MM-dd')
  var value = image
    .clip(geom)
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      scale: 30
    }).get('ssm')
  return ee.Feature(null, {value: value, date: date})
})

// Create and print the chart.
print(ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(timeSeries, 'date', ['value']))

// Export the time-series as a csv.
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: timeSeries, 
  description: 'mandera', 
  selectors: 'date, value', 
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/70f66dad02aef26b924511fe6f24ea84

> how can I name the file so I find it once it's exported?

The description property in `toDrive()` is the name your CSS file.