# How do I produce a time series of the NDVI with Landsat composites with Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, landsat

I am trying to obtain a yearly time series of the NDVI values for a series of locations, specifically 82 random squared polygons. As I need the best temporal resolution possible, dating back to the 80s at least, I've chosen to work with Landsat data, specifically Landsat missions 5-8.

I have seen that there are already calculated NDVI Landsat products available and "ready to use" in the GEE catalogue (see https://developers.google.com/earthengine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LT05_C01_T1_8DAY_NDVI) for these specific missions, but I can't figure out how to extract the specific NDVI values for my AOIs. I've loaded the AOIs in GEE and I'm able to visualize the NDVI values, but I need a table with the pixel values (preferably csvCSV) to work with. Does anybody know how can I do this? Also, does anybody knowsknow how to loop the code for the individual AOI?

Comment: For your purpose, you can adapt this script: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/356907/smos-time-series-and-export-to-csv-in-gee

Comment: Thanks very much! I will look it up